# Can I ask for examples?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I'm thinking about asking for curious examples of certain topic specific, like for  example of finite groups and sets where they can act. It is ok to ask such questions in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It would be a good question if the requirements are sufficiently narrow.   I think a post that asks merely about "finite groups and sets where they can act" would be too broad (there are many examples of many different kinds), but if this were narrowed substantially, it might be interesting.  For example you might ask for a counterexample to some proposed conjecture, such as (to give a particularly easy idea) the order of the group must divide the order of the set that it acts on.

Comment: Do you mean math.stackexchange?

Comment: Yes, I mean math.stackexchange. I don't know if this is the correct site to ask this question.

Comment: You can have a look at questions tagged [examples+big-list](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples+big-list). You will find there somewhat similar questions and you can see how they were received. Or you could try simply [examples](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples), without a (big-list) tag. But here you will have to search a bit more, since many of these questions are about various counterexamples.

Comment: And certainly before asking your question you should first try to search whether such questions already exists. For example, by going through questions tagged [group-actions+examples](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-actions+examples) or by searching for questions about [examples of group actions](https://www.google.com/search?q=examples+group+actions+site:math.stackexchange.com). Further tips about searching can be found, for example [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/links-about-searching-for-posts-on-mse) or in the tag [meta-tag:search] on meta

Comment: I didn't know that it was possible to enter various tags at same time, thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: Could you give an example for what sort of examples you'd be asking for? :P

Comment: I'm looking for finite groups acting over finite sets such that the action and the kernel of the action are not trivial. Specially $p-$groups.